# Do I need routerLink for child components?

Tags: angular

I have a main component `Customer` which is made up of a `sidenav` and a `details` component which displays the customer information:

```
<div id="customer" class="page-layout carded left-sidenav">

  <mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav class="sidenav" position="start" opened="true" mode="side" mat-is-locked-open="gt-md">
      <app-customer-sidenav></app-customer-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <div class="center">

      <div class="content-card mat-white-bg" [ngClass]="{'current-customer-selected':currentCustomer}">

        <div class="content" fxFlexAlign="row">

          <app-customer-details fxFlex></app-customer-details>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </mat-sidenav-container>

</div>
```

At this stage everything gets rendered as expected. Now, In my sidenav I have items that allow the user to go to other customer information, such as addresses, bank accounts, etc. I already have components for these.

How do I enable the linking of the these components? Using `routerLink`, `hidden`, `ngIf` or `ngSwitch`?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you have declared the routes in your app.module.ts file and used `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` in the imports of `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Yes, check out this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @gil.fernandes Yes they're declared in a childmode so I use `forChild`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you use `routerLink` for child components.

Here is a brief example on how you could use `routerLink`:

```
<li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"><!-- using exact path -->
    <a routerLink="/">Start</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a routerLink="books">Books</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a [routerLink]="['audio']">Audio</a><!-- Optional syntax here -->
</li>
```